# What is the correct way to submit Django inline formsets with prefilled data in a modal form

Tags: jquery, django, django-models, django-forms, inline-formset

In my Django app, I am querying the database tables using jquery ajax call to fill inline formsets with the json callback data.

The following image is a likely situation at the start of the process. The form/formsets are housed in a **modal** to conserve space.

[image]

I am wanting to save the user input/s (including the pre-filled values) in the respective tables by submitting the form using ajax.

The **forms** are:

```
class mappedTargModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = mappedTargModel
        fields = ('mapper_doc_type', 'mapper_name', 'mapper_target_model', 'mapper_long_text')
        widgets = {
            'mapper_doc_type': forms.TextInput(...),
            'mapper_name': forms.TextInput(...),
            'mapper_target_model': forms.TextInput(...),
            'mapper_long_text': forms.Textarea(...),
            }

class mappedTargFieldsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(mappedTargFieldsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.auto_id = False

    class Meta:
        model = mappedTargFields
        fields = ('mapped_field', 'mapped_field_verb_name', 'mapped_field_col_name', 'mapped_field_fk_table')

        widgets = {
            'mapped_field': forms.TextInput(...),
            'mapped_field_verb_name': forms.TextInput(...),
            'mapped_field_col_name': forms.TextInput(...),
            'mapped_field_fk_table': forms.TextInput(...),

            }
        exclude = ()

CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset = inlineformset_factory(
    mappedTargModel,
    mappedTargFields,
    form=mappedTargFieldsForm,
    extra=2,
    can_delete=False)
```

The **view** as adapted from (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#ajax-example) is shown below:

```
class AjaxableResponseMixin:
    """
    Mixin to add AJAX support to a form.
    Must be used with an object-based FormView (e.g. CreateView)
    """
    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super().form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # We make sure to call the parent's form_valid() method because
        # it might do some processing (in the case of CreateView, it will
        # call form.save() for example).
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            data = {
                'pk': self.object.pk,
            }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return response


class mapperObjCreateView(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    model = mappedTargModel
    form_class = mappedTargModelForm

    def clean_status(self):
        return self.instance.status
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(mapperObjCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data['mapped_fields'] = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        else:
            data['mapped_fields'] = CreateMappedTargFieldsFormset()
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        mapped_fields = context['mapped_fields']
        with transaction.atomic():

            if mapped_fields.is_valid():
                self.object = form.save()                
                mapped_fields.instance = self.object
                mapped_fields.save()

            else:
                context.update({'mapped_fields': mapped_fields})
                return self.render_to_response(context)

        return super(mapperObjCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

With the current arrangement, the form is returning errors on validation.

**What steps should be taken to ensure that the values in the form/formsets are saved to the respective tables when submitted?**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you missed the commit=False and save the many to many fields in your form_valid

here's how you should save your forms and formset
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

```
if mapped_fields.is_valid():
      self.object = form.save(commit=False)                
      mapped_fields.instance = self.object
      mapped_fields.save()
      mapped_fields.save_m2m()
```